# workflow database structure

Tags: database, workflow, entity-relationship

I am currently thinking about coding a simple workflow tool to get used with Angular, SQLAlchemy and FastAPI.

Database structure wise, I am currently looking into how the database of JIRA is structured and wonder whether this is a good approach. In the end, the JIRA database comes down to a more or less pure key/value structure for all custom fields.
Usually, this is against the recommended structure of relational databases so I wonder why this approach has been taken and if I go down the same route whether the API should PIVOT the custom fields so that it looks like a normal database record?

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. It is extremely hard to come up with a good DB structure for a workflow that is going to perform well. And any simple workflow tool ends up a maintenance nightmare with time. There is nothing simple about workflows :).

I would recommend using an existing open source tool like [temporal.io](https://temporal.io/) or [Camunda](https://camunda.com/) instead.

Comment: It shall not be a reinvention, i just want to collect some development experience. And while doing so, i want to follow a private project